# How can I change » to a blank space in multi-line \textquote?

Tags: polyglossia, quoting, csquotes

When using `\textquote` in multi-line text, subsequent lines start with `»`. I would like to change `»` to one or more blanks spaces.

Is it possible to do this?

EMV:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[ebook,11pt,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\setdefaultlanguage{spanish}

\newenvironment{scripture}
{%
    \par
    %\notoserif\small
    \parindent=0pt
    \everypar{\hangindent0.8cm\hangafter=1}%
    \let\>\talk
}
{\par}
\newcommand{\talk}[2]{%
    \par
    {% start a group
        \rightskip=0.8cm
        \hspace*{0.8cm}%
        \textquote{#1}%
        \ifx.#2.\par\else#2\fi
    }% end the group
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{scripture}   
    En aquel tiempo, Juan, que había oído en la cárcel las obras del Mesías, mandó a sus discípulos a preguntarle:

\textquote{¿Eres tú el que ha de venir o tenemos que esperar a otro?}. 

Jesús les respondió: 

\textquote{Id a anunciar a Juan lo que estáis viendo y oyendo:
    
    los ciegos ven y los cojos andan;
    
    los leprosos quedan limpios y los sordos oyen;
    
    los muertos resucitan 
    
    y los pobres son evangelizados. 
    
    ¡Y bienaventurado el que no se escandalice de mí!}. 

Al irse ellos, Jesús se puso a hablar a la gente sobre Juan: 

\textquote{¿Qué salisteis a contemplar en el desierto, una caña sacudida por el viento? ¿O qué salisteis a ver, un hombre vestido con lujo? Mirad, los que visten con lujo habitan en los palacios. Entonces, ¿a qué salisteis?, ¿a ver a un profeta? 
    
    Sí, os digo, y más que profeta. Este es de quien está escrito: 
    
    \textquote{Yo envío a mi mensajero delante de ti, el cual preparará tu camino ante ti}. 
    
    En verdad os digo que no ha nacido de mujer uno más grande que Juan el Bautista; aunque el más pequeño en el reino de los cielos es más grande que él}.
\end{scripture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I want something like that:

```
«Id a anunciar a Juan lo que estáis viendo y oyendo:
 los ciegos ven y los cojos andan;
 los leprosos quedan limpios y los sordos oyen;
 los muertos resucitan 
 y los pobres son evangelizados. 
 ¡Y bienaventurado el que no se escandalice de mí!».
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`csquotes` defines "quote styles" which are language specific.  In your case, you need to change the one for Spanish with:

```latex
\DeclareQuoteStyle[spanish]{spanish}
  {\guillemotleft}
  [\hphantom{\guillemotright}]
  {\guillemotright}
  [0.025em]
  {\textquotedblleft}
  [\hphantom{\textquotedblright}]
  {\textquotedblright}
```

I used there `\hphantom{\textquotedblright}` to get "the space that would have been needed for the quote", as I thought it would grant you better alignment in general than just a "space".

In full:

```latex
\documentclass[ebook,11pt,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\setdefaultlanguage{spanish}

\DeclareQuoteStyle[spanish]{spanish}
  {\guillemotleft}
  % [\guillemotright] % <- This was the original definition
  [\hphantom{\guillemotright}]
  {\guillemotright}
  [0.025em]
  {\textquotedblleft}
  % [\textquotedblright] % <- This was the original definition
  [\hphantom{\textquotedblright}]
  {\textquotedblright}

\newenvironment{scripture}
{%
    \par
    %\notoserif\small
    \parindent=0pt
    \everypar{\hangindent0.8cm\hangafter=1}%
    \let\>\talk
}
{\par}
\newcommand{\talk}[2]{%
    \par
    {% start a group
        \rightskip=0.8cm
        \hspace*{0.8cm}%
        \textquote{#1}%
        \ifx.#2.\par\else#2\fi
    }% end the group
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{scripture}
    En aquel tiempo, Juan, que había oído en la cárcel las obras del Mesías, mandó a sus discípulos a preguntarle:

\textquote{¿Eres tú el que ha de venir o tenemos que esperar a otro?}.

Jesús les respondió:

\textquote{Id a anunciar a Juan lo que estáis viendo y oyendo:

    los ciegos ven y los cojos andan;

    los leprosos quedan limpios y los sordos oyen;

    los muertos resucitan

    y los pobres son evangelizados.

    ¡Y bienaventurado el que no se escandalice de mí!}.

Al irse ellos, Jesús se puso a hablar a la gente sobre Juan:

\textquote{¿Qué salisteis a contemplar en el desierto, una caña sacudida por el viento? ¿O qué salisteis a ver, un hombre vestido con lujo? Mirad, los que visten con lujo habitan en los palacios. Entonces, ¿a qué salisteis?, ¿a ver a un profeta?

    Sí, os digo, y más que profeta. Este es de quien está escrito:

    \textquote{Yo envío a mi mensajero delante de ti, el cual preparará tu camino ante ti}.

    En verdad os digo que no ha nacido de mujer uno más grande que Juan el Bautista; aunque el más pequeño en el reino de los cielos es más grande que él}.
\end{scripture}

\end{document}
```

Which results in:

[image]